# Created Stored procedures in my CosmosDb, how can I access them through my .net wep API (which is connected to my cosmosDb)

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, server-side

I've made server side stored procedure named sample ( it's the default stored procedure) how can I call it inside my .net web API ?

Answer (score 4):

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ServerSideScripts/Program.cs

Using the [V3 .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet-standard), you can execute your stored procedure like so:

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("connection string");
Container container = client.GetContainer("YourDbName", "YourContainerName");
StoredProcedureExecuteResponse response = await container.Scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync(
                "sample", // your stored procedure name
                new PartitionKey("Partition Key you want to run it on"),
                new dynamic[] { "Your First parameter", "Your second parameter" });

// If your stored procedure returns some information, you can use the Type of the data you expect. For example, if you expect a string
StoredProcedureExecuteResponse<string> responseWithData = await container.Scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(
                "sample", // your stored procedure name
                new PartitionKey("Partition Key you want to run it on"),
                new dynamic[] { "Your First parameter", "Your second parameter" });
```

If you are creating a Web API, please make sure you maintain a [Singleton instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#sdk-usage) of the CosmosClient, often registering it as part of the Startup. Do not create new instances of the CosmosClient for each operation.

This means that, in your `Startup.cs` where services are being registered in the [DI container](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2), you can add it there:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other code you might already have
    CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("connection string");
    services.AddSingleton(client);
}
```

And inject the `CosmosClient` instance in your Controller:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly CosmosClient cosmosClient;
    public MyController(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
    {
        this.cosmosClient = cosmosClient;    
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod()
    {
        // execute the stored procedure or use this.cosmosClient

    }
}
```

Full Web API sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-dotnet-core-todo-app

Comment: Where exactly can I put this code? Does this go in controller of my Web API or program.cs. Could you specify the file where I can put this code.

Comment: Edited answer to be more explicit

Comment: Hahahaha no, we are all in the same boat, we are all learning.

Comment: dear god, we are trying to make a asp .Net web api using which we want to connect to our cosmosdb and utilize the stored procedures which we have created in the cosmosdb portal, we were able to work with your Console project but are not able to understand how to make a web api using your example. Please help us because we are really new to all this.

Comment: The sample at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-dotnet-core-todo-app is a Web API ASP.NET Core application, not a console project.

Comment: The sample at github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-dotnet-core-todo-app doesn't have stored procedure implementation.. could you tell us how to implement that in the above project.

Comment: Use the same project to understand how to add the CosmosClient to your Web API, check the Startup.cs file, it will register the client like in my answer. Then if you want to call the stored procedure in one of your API Controllers, you can inject it like I did in my answer and inside your API methods, execute it using `container.Scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync` like in the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked, please do remember to mark the answers to help people in the future.