# How to access the CosmosDb stored procedure created in the azure portal through our .net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

We have created a CosmosDb,created a container, connected it to my .net Web api, created a stored procedure in the under the container. My problem is accessing that stored procedure through my .net web API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Created Stored procedures in my CosmosDb, how can I access them through my .net wep API (which is connected to my cosmosDb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766288/created-stored-procedures-in-my-cosmosdb-how-can-i-access-them-through-my-net)

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync` method with .net code behind your web api route.

Sample code:

```
dynamic newItem = new
{
    category = "Personal",
    name = "Groceries",
    description = "Pick up strawberries",
    isComplete = false
};

Uri uri = UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("myDatabase", "myContainer", "spCreateToDoItem");
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("Personal") };
var result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(uri, options, newItem);
```

Please see more details from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs).